# comma seperation for each cell of dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If there are any cells with a comma (**if condition**), I would like to separate them out and pick the last one, something like:

The original table is like here below:

| index | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | banana | orange |
| 1 | grapes, Citrus | apples |
| 2 | tangerine, tangerine | melons, pears |

which is going to be changed to like below:

| index | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | banana | orange |
| 1 | Citrus | apples |
| 2 | tangerine | pears |

As you can see, for each cell the second fruit name was selected by iterating over all cells in dataframe.

In order to do that, I would like to use **apply** with a function that separates by comma, but please let me know if there's a better way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access that with `.str` accessor:

```
>>> df
 
                         x1             x2
index                                     
0                    banana         orange
1            grapes, Citrus         apples
2      tangerine, tangerine  melons, pears

>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.str.split(', ').str[-1], axis=1)

              x1      x2
index                   
0         banana  orange
1         Citrus  apples
2      tangerine   pears
```

Or, in steps:

```
>>> df['x1'] = df['x1'].str.split(', ').str[-1]
>>> df['x2'] = df['x2'].str.split(', ').str[-1]
```